# Trouble outputting font property using less variables

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using twitter bootstrap with less and I have the following:

```
@serifFontFamily: 'Droid Serif', "Georgia", Times, serif;
@baseFontSize: 100%/1.5;

font: @baseFontSize @serfiFontFamily;
```

it produces:

```
font: 66.666666667% 'Droid Serif', "Georgia", Times, serif
```

but I want to output this:

```
font: 100%/1.5 'Droid Serif', "Georgia", Times, serif
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
@baseFontSize: ~"100%/1.5";
```

and less will interpret it as a string and not as an expression.

Comment: I'm so sorry. That was my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I had decomposed the property font in 3 properties:

```
font-size: @baseFontSize;
font-family: @baseFontFamily;
line-height: @baseLineHeight;
```

and my variables:

```
@baseFontSize:          100%;
@baseFontFamily:        'Droid Serif', "Georgia", Times, serif;
@baseLineHeight:        1.5;
```

than it works properly!