# How do I write font in LESS CSS?

Tags: css, fonts, less, parse-error

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I just picked up WinLess (the compiler I'm using) about two days ago and I've just vaguely learned the basis of LESS. Anyways, I'm having a problem with this bit of code:

```
// Font
    @verdana: font-family:"verdana";
    @sans: font-family:"sans-serif";
```

When I do compile this I get this message:

> ParseError: Unrecognized input in  on line 4, column 3:

```
3 // Font
4 @verdana: font-family:"verdana";
5 @sans: font-famlit:"sans-serif";
```

Can anyone give me a hand? Thanks!

Comment: What's the goal with this? Have you read the reference? http://lesscss.org

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble outputting font property using less variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159576/trouble-outputting-font-property-using-less-variables)

Comment: I don't really need the font sizes or anything just the actual font family.

Comment: Actually Paulie_D you were correct, thanks a lot for that link. Much appreciated by everyone who's helped.

Answer (score 1):

### For LESS 1.7+

They have now added [rulesets](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) that work like this:

```
@verdana: {font-family:"verdana"};

.myClass {
    @verdana();
}
```

**Note the syntax**: you pass a bracketed `{}` set of properties, and access it with the parenthesis `()` after the variable name, much like a mixin. As you can see, it also functions a lot like a mixin (similar to lucian's answer), but it has the added value that *it can be passed as an argument*, so this is possible:

**LESS**

```
@verdana: {font-family:"verdana"};

.myMix(@font) {
    @font();
}

.test {
  .myMix(@verdana);
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.test {
  font-family: "verdana";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it like this: `.myfont{ font-family:"some family, some generic family"}` and then use it like this: `div{ .myfont; }`

Answer (score 0):

i only know it in this way :

```
@variable_name: 'individual_font_name', Verdana, sans-serif;
```

a font variable with a name, a font name like "My_Verdana" and the main font and the second as example for a failure of the main-font.

hope this helps, greetings.